# How to specify shared template variable with two template template parameters?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I'm trying to build a mini test framework. I have one function that takes in two List-like variables that are composed of the same type and I plan on using template template parameters as part of the interface. So far, I have this,

```
    template <typename C, template <class> class A, template <class> class B>
    static inline void assertEquals(const A<C>& expected, const B<C>& actual) {
      auto success = 0, failure = 0;

      for (auto iter1 = expected.cbegin(), iter2 = actual.cbegin();
           iter1 != expected.cend() && iter2 != actual.cend(); ++iter1, ++iter2) {
        if (Test::assertEquals<C>(*iter1, *iter2)) {
          ++success;
        } else {
          ++failure;
        }
      }

      cout << "Success: " << success << endl
           << "Failure: " << failure << endl;
    }
```

The `assertEquals` in the if condition is another function. My question is, is the interface correct? Secondly, how would I use it? I've tried this to no avail,

```
    Test::assertEquals<int, std::vector, std::vector>(haystack, needle);
```

`Test::` is simply the class that the function resides in and `haystack` and `needle` are of type `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: `std::vector<T>` is in fact `std::vector<T, Alloc>`.

Comment: Did you really need to provide `C` in `Test::assertEquals<C>` ? could it be deduce from arguments instead ? (if yes, `assertEquals(const T1& expected, const T2& actual)` is enough).

Comment: @Jarod42 Right. Does that mean I cannot initialize it as `std::vector<T>`? I thought that since `Alloc` is a function of of `T`, I can simply include `T`. That seems to be a key issue in what I'm doing wrong, though, as @TartanLlama also pointed out

Comment: You can say `std::vector<T>` because `std::vector` defines a default value to use as the second template argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interface won't accept `std::vector`, because it actually takes two template arguments: the contained type and an allocator.

You could change your template signature to accept variadic template templates, like this:

```
template <typename C, template <class...> class A, template <class...> class B>
static inline void assertEquals(const A<C>& expected, const B<C>& actual) {
```

Or you could set the default parameter explicitly:

```
template <typename C, 
          template <class, class = std::allocator<C>> class A, 
          template <class, class = std::allocator<C>> class B>
    void assertEquals(const A<C>& expected, const B<C>& actual) {
```

However, you're probably better off just getting `C` from the STL container member types, like this:

```
template <class A, class B>
void assertEquals(const A& expected, const B& actual) {
    static_assert(std::is_same<typename A::value_type, typename B::value_type>::value,
                  "Containers must have the same value type");
    using C = typename A::value_type;
    //...
```

This is a much more simple interface. For all of the above options, the compiler can deduce the template arguments for you, so just call it like:

```
assertEquals(haystack, needle);
```

Comment: That works too I guess. If I wanted to go the template template parameter route, would that mean that `C` is now a pack variable and using it in the function parameters would look like this, `... const A<C...>& expected,...`?

Comment: No, `C` is still a single class. Making the template template variadic essentially tells the compiler to accept any template template so that you can let the default argument take effect without having to declare it explicitly.

Comment: So how would the instantiation of this interface look like?

Comment: You can just call it with the runtime arguments and let the compiler deduce the types, see my edit.

Comment: I forgot that templates could be deduced like that. That's less of an eyesore than what I had. Thanks!